# Cordova camera is not working in Android marshmallow

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, camera

Cordova camera is not working in Android marshmallow. App crashes when the camera captured picture are selected. This is the same case when attaching the image from photo library. I can access the Camera and photo library, but app get crashed once i selected the photo after capturing using camera. The issue is not found in KitKat version.
Below i included the Content security policy used in my code and also the cordova camera code.

CSP meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src gap: *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' http://....">
```

cordova camera code :

```
src = (src == 'library') ? Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY : Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA; 
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, 
        {
          quality: 40,
          destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI, 
          sourceType: src,
          encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
          saveToPhotoAlbum: false
        }
     );
```

Cordova Version is 7.0.1 and Android platform version = '6.2.3'

Also here i am attaching the error i got in Android Studio.

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: did you asked  runtime permission

Comment: I think the problem will be with backbutton . event fired.

Comment: yes i got the run time camera permission